# merge multiple dynamic and static variables R

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I am trying to merge / join data in R and am running into a problem.

I need to specify multiple variables from each dataset, and then one variable from dataset 2 with a static value.

Something like

```
DF1 <- data.frame(ID=c('1','2','3','4'),
            Date=c('1 Apr','1 Apr','1 Apr','1 Apr'),
            Sale=c('1000','1000','1000','1000'))
DF2 <- data.frame(ID=c('1','1','2','3','4'),
            Date=c('1 Apr','1 Apr','1 Apr','1 Apr','1 Apr'),
            Sale=c('1000','1000','1000','1000','1000'),
            Key=c('P','S','P','P','P'))


        DF1
ID  |  Date  |  Sale  | 
-----------------------
1     1 Apr    1000
2     1 Apr    1000
3     1 Apr    1000
4     1 Apr    1000

        DF2
ID  |  Date  |  Sale  |  Key  |
-------------------------------
1     1 Apr    1000       P
1     1 Apr    1000       S
2     1 Apr    1000       P
3     1 Apr    1000       P
4     1 Apr    1000       P
```

I need to join for the three variables with same names in DF1 and DF2, and where Key == P from DF2. I am familiar with syntax for merge and left_join, but I cannot get them to work if I try and specify that the key variable in DF2 needs to == a static value, rather than it must match something from DF1.

Something like:

```
DF3 <- left_join(DF1, DF2, c("ID1.x" = "ID.y", 
"Date.x" = "Date.y", "Sale.x" = "Sale.y", DF2$Key == "P"), 
na.matches = "never")
```

I realize that won't work, but hopefully it provides some idea of what I want to do. One variable is static and acts as a filter in DF2.

If anyone asks, no, I cannot simply delete all rows where the Key != P.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `merge(DF1, subset(DF2, Key != "P"))`. You don't have to delete the rows, just subset during the merge. Just filter rather than merging by static values.

Comment: I'm running into headroom / RAM allocation problems...there are many other variables in the dataframes and 10,000 plus rows in each. I need to be able to specify a list of 3-4 variables to join on w common values, and then in addition, to only look for rows in DF2 where Key == P.

Comment: If you don't have enough RAM to work with the data in R, you can look into storing your data in a database and querying the database for the data you need. There is just no function in base R that does this very specific, uncommon type of join. Are you sure there is a 1-1 match on your columns? 10,000 rows doesn't really seem like that many.